# Как запоминать наибольшее значение в переменную без массива

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

Всем привет! Есть body которое прыгает,

```
public void jump(){
    body.setLinearVelocity(0,JUMP_HEIGHT/PPM);
}
```

Есть переменная score в котором должно находиться самое большое значение **высоты** прыжка;
Пытаюсь вывести его на экран так:

```
public int currentScore(float ballPos){
    int score = 0;
    if(score < ballPos){
        score = (int)Math.floor(gameScreen.getBallPos());
        return score;
    }
    return 0;
}

public void draw(){
    ballPos = (int)Math.floor(gameScreen.getBallPos());

    batch.begin();
    scoreText.draw(batch,currentScore(ballPos)+"m",20,H-30);
    if(gameScreen.getBallPos() < gameScreen.getCamPos()-5){

        gameOverText.draw(batch,"  Game Over\n Your score: "+currentScore(ballPos)+"\nTap to restart!",W/4,H/1.6f);
        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }
    }
    batch.end();
}
```

---

Но на экран выводиться его позиция по вертикали, т.е. Например персонаж прыгнул и его высота равно 5м но на экран выводиться 1...5м но потом обратно до 0м опускается. А надо чтобы сохранилось чтобы в дальнейшем при еще высоком прыжке сохранялась высокое значение. Очень надеюсь понятно объяснил). Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Я предполагаю это из-за того, что нет переменной объекта, которая хранит наибольший результат. Не понятно зачем нужен метод #currentScore.Грубо говоря если переданное число меньше больше нуля то он вызывает метод #getBallPos и округляет его значение. Что делает метод #getBallPos и какова логика метода #currentScore?

Comment: #getBallPos - берет Y позицию тела,
#currentScore - это я пытался сохранить наибольший результат в переменную